# I want to add new field in checkout page. Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, onepage-checkout, grid

[image]

As i am using cash on delivery method, so i want to add new field (like Date and time), customer give date and time when he wants the order at his/her place. 
[image]
And then also show that date and time on admin->order grid.
 Please help as much as you can. Thank you

Comment: check this http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2015/08/20/checkout-add-extra-address-field/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly Follow Below Link For Adding Date & Time :

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/order-delivery-time-slot.html

Comment: This extension is not compatible with Magento 1.9.2.3.

Comment: I already install this module in magento 1.9.2.3 and its working fine

Comment: I will accept your answer when the problem will be solved bro :). Now i got a new problem. This extension is not supporting PHP version 7.0 on ubuntu.  So, now i am degrading PHP version. Still got many issues. :

Comment: ok bro still waiting...